# Mathematica JDBC error

Tags: database, jdbc, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to run a Mathematica program (that I didn't write) locally. I have run it on another machine (that I didn't set up).

I've set up the necessary mysql database, but I keep getting this error:

```
JDBC::error: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. >>
```

I can't figure out how to get any nested exceptions from Java and I can connect to mysql using the user/pass I'm sending.

Help!?

Comment: My first question: is this reproducible behavior on this new machine? Secondly, if you could tell us which package you are using or the command that is causing this message you increase the chances of getting help.

Comment: This error comes from DatabaseLink in Mathematica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to the database from the machine in question?  Something like

```
TracePrint[COMMANDHERE[], DatabaseLink`OpenSQLConnection[__]]
```

may shed some light on what parameters are being used.

Comment: I didn't have the mysql jar file in my classpath. Thanks!